# Javascript - dynamically generate an infinitely nested Array from a flat Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, treeview

I have a list of employees that I get by AJAX request form the server side, and every item in this list is the parent of the item below it, except the last child, so on client side, I end up with a JavaScript array like this:

```
data = [
{ FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Manager", ID: "5656" },
{ FirstName: "Sam", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Sale", ID: "654654" },
{ FirstName: "Sarah", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Employee", ID: "6541" },
{ FirstName: "Sally", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Clerk", ID: "8754" },
{ FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Clerk", ID: "654564" }
];
```

So far so good, now my problem is that I want to use [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview), and this component needs a JavaScript array like this:

```
var tree = [
  {
      text: "John - Manager",
      nodes: [
        {
            text: "Sam - Sale",
            nodes: [
              {
                  text: "Sarah - Employee",
                  nodes: [
                      {
                          text: "Sally - Clerk",
                          nodes: [
                              {
                                  text: "Joe - Clerk"
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
];
```

My tree is not static, so I have to generate it dynamically, how can I dynamically generate an infinitely nested array like this using JavaScript?

Comment: you can google linked list js and look around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proposal features [`Array.prototype.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).

> The `reduceRight()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from right-to-left) has to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var data = [
        { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Manager", ID: "5656" },
        { FirstName: "Sam", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Sale", ID: "654654" },
        { FirstName: "Sarah", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Employee", ID: "6541" },
        { FirstName: "Sally", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Clerk", ID: "8754" },
        { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Clerk", ID: "654564" }
    ],
    tree = data.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
        var o = { text: a.FirstName + ' - ' + a.Position };
        if (r) {
            o.nodes = r;
        }
        return [o];
    }, undefined);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var data = [
        { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Manager", ID: "5656" },
        { FirstName: "Sam", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Sale", ID: "654654" },
        { FirstName: "Sarah", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Employee", ID: "6541" },
        { FirstName: "Sally", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Clerk", ID: "8754" },
        { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Doe", Position: "Clerk", ID: "654564" }
    ], tree = [];

data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    var o = { text: a.FirstName + ' - ' + a.Position, nodes: [] };
    r.push(o);
    return o.nodes;
}, tree);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

The difference between the two proposals is in the first case the iteration and building of the array/object from the last row and the return is always the complete tree.

The second proposal features a given array and returns the reference to the included row/nodes. The building scheme is from the first row to the last, as opposite of the first proposal.

The drawback of the second solution is an empty array `nodes`.

Comment: Thank you so much Nina, your solution helped a lot. If you think my question doesn't describe the problem as well as it should, please consider editing it to suit your given answer.